# Why does my code return a broken pipe error when passing a manager.dict object as an argument?

Tags: python, multiprocessing

When running the following function:

```
#returns list of hostIds on network;
def getHostsOnNetwork(surveyResults, hosts):
    notifEnabledMacs = [host['macAddr']
        for host in hosts.values()
        if host['notificationEnabled']
   ]
    macsOnNetwork = [host['mac'] for host in surveyResults]

    return [host['id']
        for host in hosts.values()
        if host['macAddr'] in macsOnNetwork
    ]
```

I pass a `manager.dict` object as 'hosts'. I receive the following error as a result:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/usr/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/process.py", line 315, in _bootstrap
     self.run()
   File "/usr/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/process.py", line 108, in run
     self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
   File "main.py", line 101, in notifsProducer
     oldHostSet = currentHostSet
   File "/home/patrick/notificationApp;/networking.py", line 82, in getHostsOnNetwork
     for host in hosts.values()
   File "<string>", line 2, in values
   File "/usr/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/managers.py", line 834, in _callmethod
     conn.send((self._id, methodname, args, kwds))
   File "/usr/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 206, in send
     self._send_bytes(_ForkingPickler.dumps(obj))
   File "/usr/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 411, in _send_bytes
     self._send(header + buf)
   File "/usr/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 368, in _send
     n = write(self._handle, buf)
 BrokenPipeError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
```

It seems that the compiler is trying to make a write to the manager.dict object, but why? I don't alter any of its values in the function. How can I resolve this error?

Any guidance is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Managers create proxy objects in multiple processes. Pipes keep everything in sync. Exactly how that's done is a black box - you need to read the source to find out. But one proxy asking another what its revision is likely to happen when you touch it. My guess is that your other process has exited and this proxy can no longer validate itself.

Comment: @tdelaney I do not think that's the case. One process deals with UI, which remains interactive throughout. The other process runs in an infinite loop, hence it cannot exit. Therefore, I can confidently say that both processs are running. Given that the child process only needs to read the data structure and does not write to it, is there an alternative data structure that may suit me better?

Comment: I don't see any kind of data modification going on here.  Rather, the "writing" is part of forking a coprocess, as state is pickled up and written over a socket as part of that operation.

Comment: @Steve So what's the issue, and how do I resolve it?

Comment: I have no idea.  I was just commenting on your statement "It seems that the compiler is trying to make a write to the manager.dict object".  I don't read that at all from the stacktrace.  What it's writing to is a socket, not your object.  This makes sense, as that's the kind of think that would cause a "broken pipe" error.